# Yandex Contest, stdin, stdout

Tags: python, stdin, яндекс-контест

Всем добрый день. Решаю задачу из архива Яндекс Контеста:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Cтолкнулся со следующей проблемой: в тетрадке решение работает, но на сайте выдаёт ошибку RE (ошибка во время исполнения), подозреваю, что в тетрадке я неправильно воспроизвёл формат входных данных и, соответственно, решающую функцию настроил на неправильный формат. Входные данные создавал следующим образом:

```
input_data = []
file = open('input.txt', 'w')
sub = []

l = 100
k = 1000

for i in range(l):
    input_prom = []
    if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
        for j in range(0,k):
            a,b = generate1()
            input_prom.append(a)
            input_prom.append(b)
        sub.append(1)
    else:
        for j in range(0,k):
            a,b = generate2()
            input_prom.append(a)
            input_prom.append(b)
        sub.append(2)
    input_data = ' '.join(str(el) for el in input_prom)
    file.write(input_data + '\n')

file.close()
```

Получаю вроде бы то, что требуется (пример для формата 5х10):

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
 input = file.read()
 print(input)
file.close()

-0.395 -0.501 0.022 -0.509 -0.719 -0.638 0.348 0.052 0.418 -0.015
-0.093 -0.05 0.014 0.013 -0.261 -0.613 -0.736 -0.582 -0.874 -0.442
-0.155 -0.463 0.451 0.361 0.715 0.443 -0.099 -0.708 -0.169 -0.749
0.331 -0.694 0.836 -0.535 -0.036 0.833 -0.824 -0.198 0.416 0.191
0.287 0.737 -0.784 -0.472 0.733 0.417 0.074 0.375 -0.592 0.289
```

После этого применял этот код (который и отправлял в форму на Яндексе):

```
import numpy as np
lst = []
lst_all = []

with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
  lines = file.readlines()
  for line in lines:
        lst = line.split()
        lst_all.append(lst)
        
output = list(map(lambda x: np.linalg.norm(x)/len(x), lst_all))
output = [1 if x < 0.010151637746724607 else 2 for x in output]

for i in output:
    print(i)
```

Был бы рад помощи с проблемой, спасибо.

Comment: что за тетрадка?

Comment: Я что-то не пойму - вы np.linalg.norm скармливаете список строк?

Comment: Как приложить тетрадку к посту? Или только через pastebin?

Comment: @MBo, вроде в np.linalg.norm уходит один набор точек. Но повторюсь, локально все работает, всем наборам присваиваются нужный номер алгоритма

Comment: Набор точек или набор строк? В описании задачи ничего не про файлы - значит, вам надо читать из стандартного консольного ввода функцией input() ?

Comment: @MBo, `lambda` иттерирует по `lst_all` и выдаёт в `х` для `np.linalg.norm` набор из 1000 точек. В описании задачи написано "стандартный ввод или input.txt". Можно переписать задачу на чтение из input(), но я хочу разобраться в каком именно формате подаются данные, чтобы правильно задать свою функцию.